# 'MasterViewController' does not have a member named 'managedContextObject'

Tags: ios, swift

I am just trying to learn how to do a master-detail app with a tutorial (good tutorial links more than welcome).  As I was editing the AppDelegate.swift file, I noticed two errors which I thought was strange since they occurred in the APple provided code.

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  SplitRes
//
//  Created by  on 1/13/15.
//  Copyright  All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as UINavigationController
    let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as MasterViewController
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Split view

func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController:UIViewController!, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController:UIViewController!) -> Bool {
    if let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController {
        if let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController {
            if topAsDetailController.detailItem == nil {
                // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "jcv.SplitRes" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SplitRes", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SplitRes.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

}

This line:

```
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
```

produces the error mentioned as the subject of this question.  I've googled but cannot find any answers and am confused as to why this boilerplate code would provide an error.

The MasterViewController.swift:

```
//
//  MasterViewController.swift
//  SplitRes
//
//  Created by J on 1/13/15.
//   All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var restaurantNames: [String]?
var restaurantDetails: [String]?

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var objects = NSMutableArray()

//var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
//var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320.0, height: 600.0)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    restaurantNames = ["Joe's Taco Hut","Tom's Rib Shack","Betty's Corner Food","Jon Dough's Food","Luke's Dogs"]
    restaurantDetails = ["Mexican - $ - *","BBQ - $$ - **","American - $$$ - ***","Bakery - $$ - ****","Fast Food - $ *"]

    /*
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    */

    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    newManagedObject.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timeStamp")

    // Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    return restaurantNames!.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",
        forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = restaurantNames![indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

/*
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
*/

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject)

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description
}

// MARK: - Fetched results controller

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: selfmanagedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
         //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}    
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Update:
            self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
        case .Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

/*
 // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed.

 func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
     // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
     self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
 */
```

}

Comment: You need to show us the MaterViewController. It is the one missing the managedObjectContext property.

Comment: Added.  Errors happening in var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController section.

Comment: The managedObjectContext property is completely commented out, no wonder it doesn't exist

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Sorry, am a beginner.  The tutorial (seemed) to indicate to remove all the existing vars and replace it with theirs but did not mention keeping the managedObjectContext var.